# Adobe AIR ADT Create Package missing icons on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: android, air, adobe, package, windows-7-x64

I am trying to package up my first android app and am having trouble with the icon png files.

The directory structure of my package is as follows:

```
bin
cer
  -- Jazz Cert.p12
src
  -- assets
       -- icon16.png
       -- icon32.png
       -- icon48.png
       -- icon72.png
       -- icon128.png
  -- test.swf
  -- test.xml
```

The contents of my descriptor file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0"> 
    <id>com.jazz.android.viewer.jazztest.DesignByJazz.1-0</id> 
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber> 
    <filename>Design Jazz Test App</filename> 
    <versionLabel>1.0.0</versionLabel>
    <supportedProfiles>mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
    <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
    <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
    <initialWindow> 
        <content>./test.swf</content> 
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio><!-- landscape -->
        <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <renderMode>gpu</renderMode> <!-- cpu -->
    </initialWindow> 
    <android>
       <manifestAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
        <manifest>
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
           <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
           <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
           <application android:enabled="true">
               <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                   <intent-filter>
                       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                       <category android:name= "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                   </intent-filter>
               </activity>
           </application>
        </manifest>
        ]]>
        </manifestAdditions>
    </android>
    <icon> 
        <image16x16>./assets/icon16.png</image16x16>
        <image32x32>./assets/icon32.png</image32x32>    
        <image48x48>./assets/icon48.png</image48x48>
        <image72x72>./assets/icon72.png</image72x72>
        <image128x128>./assets/icon128.png</image128x128>
    </icon>
</application>
```

And the errors I am receiving are as follows:

```
C:\AIRSDK_Compiler\projects\libracalc\src>adt -package -target apk -storetype pk
cs12 -keystore ../cer/JazzCert.p12 ../bin/test.apk test.xml test.swf
password:
C:\AIRSDK_Compiler\projects\libracalc\src\test.xml: error 303: Icon assets/icon1
6.png is missing from package
C:\AIRSDK_Compiler\projects\libracalc\src\test.xml: error 303: Icon assets/icon1
28.png is missing from package
C:\AIRSDK_Compiler\projects\libracalc\src\test.xml: error 303: Icon assets/icon4
8.png is missing from package
C:\AIRSDK_Compiler\projects\libracalc\src\test.xml: error 303: Icon assets/icon7
2.png is missing from package
C:\AIRSDK_Compiler\projects\libracalc\src\test.xml: error 303: Icon assets/icon3
2.png is missing from package
```

I have tried changing the paths in the xml file to "assets/" || "./assets/" etc but can't get it to work please help :-)

Comment: Hi, I think you also need to add the assets folder path in the command line (at least you have to do it when packaging for desktop) so the assets are included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to simon314's comment as it lead me to the answer.

It seems you can package individual files so I just included all the icon files in the command line like so:

```
c:\AIRSDK_Compiler\projects\libracalc\src>adt -package -target apk -storetype pk
cs12 -keystore ../cer/JazzCert.p12 ../bin/test.apk test.xml test.swf assets/icon
16.png assets/icon32.png assets/icon48.png assets/icon72.png assets/icon128.png
password:
NOTE: The application has been packaged with a shared runtime.
```

Success!!